# How to sort RecyclerView based on some int value stored in recycler list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want recycler list sort by Ascending or Descending order based on **randomNum** value in it. I don't know how to sort recycler list locally. Recycler list populate based on Firestore data so it is difficult to sort like other method available on internet and I am beginner to java programming so any help would be appreciated. All data in RecyclerView comes from Firestore. My code below ----

```
CollectionReference collectionReference = db.collection("products");
Query resultQuery = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("name", "xyz");

FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ProductModel> resultOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ProductModel>().setQuery(resultQuery, ProductModel.class).build();

    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter resultAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ProductModel, ProductViewHolder>(resultOptions) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_card, parent, false);
            return new ProductViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ProductViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ProductModel model) {
           
            holder.name.setText(model.getName());
            holder.price.setText(model.getPrice());
            Random random = new Random();
            randomNum = random.nextInt(1000);
        }
    };
    resultAdapter.startListening();
    productList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    productList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    productList.setAdapter(resultAdapter);
}

private class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView name, price;
    private int randomNum;
    

    public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price); 
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean you want to basically shuffle your query?

Comment: @MehranBehbahani I want to sort query result based on randomNum , highest number to lowest or vice-versa.

Comment: how is that different from shuffling?